# Code Map Missing in Visual Studio 15 - Preview 4

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-map

Code Map feature was working fine in Visual Studio 15 - Preview 3. but after installation of Preview 4, Code Map option is disappeared. (Initially I have installed Workload - .NET desktop development)

After little search, I found in [Release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes) that, Architecture Diagrams and Analysis Tools require other workloads to be installed. So I added suggested workloads - Web Development, Windows desktop development with C++

but even after adding these components, I am unable to create/open existing code maps.

Answer (score 4):

`Code Map` is fully supported in Visual Studio 2017. Please make sure you use the installer for the Enterprise SKU, as Code Map is not available in Professional / Community.

`Code Map` is a recommended component for the .Net Desktop Development workload, but you can install it in any workload if you go to Individual Components and look for it under `Code Tools`:

[image]

Other possible issues you might have run into:

- upgrades between pre-release versions are not supported AFAIK, please make sure you do a fresh install
- if all else fails, open a developer command prompt and run "devenv /setup" and try again

Comment: do you happen to know how to make the UML options appear in the Architecture menu for VS2017 RC Enterprise? Or how I would go about accessing the UML creation tools? Thanks

Comment: Sorry Ben, UML has been cut starting with VS 2017. We worked on improving the validation with Layer Diagram, so that's the only one left.

Comment: understood, thanks for letting me know @Bogdan. I have been searching for a while but this info doesn't seem to have been made readily available.

Comment: We mostly publish the news on the MSDN ALM Blog page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/ and here's the announcement: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/10/14/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/