# Can't see code map/show stack graph visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, stack-trace, code-map

I don't know what happend but my **Code Map is missing** from visual studio 2015. Also when i go to Debug there always was something like Show Stack Graph or something which would open graph of function calls etc, and it is missing now.

Anyone had same problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code Map is only available in Visual Studio Enterprise.

For Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise it is a mandatory component, so you will always get it no matter what options you select in the installer.

For Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, it is an optional component. See this question on how to make sure you install it:

[Code Map Missing in Visual Studio 15 - Preview 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350644/code-map-missing-in-visual-studio-15-preview-4)